# Filter json query complex nested list

Tags: json, ansible

I have the following:

```
          {
              "additionalInfo": [],
              "id": "8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2",
              "instanceTenantId": "62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994",
              "name": "Global",
              "siteHierarchy": "8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2",
              "siteNameHierarchy": "Global"
          },
          {
              "additionalInfo": [
                  {
                      "attributes": {
                          "addressInheritedFrom": "0d5e4dc7-ce4e-4aff-bf9f-bb8242797dce",
                          "type": "area"
                      },
                      "nameSpace": "Location"
                  }
              ],
              "id": "1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69",
              "instanceTenantId": "62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994",
              "name": "SOUTH SOUTH",
              "parentId": "90483b39-e1b3-4135-b1b9-3b7b94d5b2f5",
              "siteHierarchy": "8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2/0d5e4dc7-ce4e-4aff-bf9f-bb8242797dce/90483b39-e1b3-4135-b1b9-3b7b94d5b2f5/1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69",
              "siteNameHierarchy": "Global/MY NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/SOUTH SOUTH"
          },
          {
              "additionalInfo": [
                  {
                      "attributes": {
                          "floorIndex": "1",
                          "imageURL": "",
                          "isCadFile": "false",
                          "rfModel": "103103"
                      },
                      "nameSpace": "mapsSummary"
                  },
                  {
                      "attributes": {
                          "height": "15.0",
                          "length": "100.0",
                          "offsetX": "0.0",
                          "offsetY": "0.0",
                          "width": "100.0"
                      },
                      "nameSpace": "mapGeometry"
                  },
                  {
                      "attributes": {
                          "address": "Lisbon",
                          "addressInheritedFrom": "d518b161-85f7-434c-91ae-3eface9cc1d5",
                          "type": "floor"
                      },
                      "nameSpace": "Location"
                  }
              ],
              "id": "33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47",
              "instanceTenantId": "62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994",
              "name": "FLOOR-1",
              "parentId": "d518b161-85f7-434c-91ae-3eface9cc1d5",
              "siteHierarchy": "8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2/0d5e4dc7-ce4e-4aff-bf9f-bb8242797dce/90483b39-e1b3-4135-b1b9-3b7b94d5b2f5/aef6ef8c-d3ba-4a1c-a0e7-fad4e00e1c5f/d518b161-85f7-434c-91ae-3eface9cc1d5/33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47",
              "siteNameHierarchy": "Global/MY NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/OEIRAS/ALGES/FLOOR-1"
          }
```

What I want to do is to filter the json query in such a way that obtain the "id" value only if there's and attribute "type": "floor"

Initially I tried to at least save only the attributes if type was equal to floor using the following with no success (among other options):

```
    - name: Save results to variable 
      set_fact:
        my_test: "{{ results.dnac_response | json_query(myquery) }}"
      vars: 
        myquery: "response[*].additionalInfo[*].attributes[? type=='floor].type"
```

But, ideally what I would like is to get a list of "id" values under the condition indicated above. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

---

Additional comment

With this:

```
  - name: Save results to variable 2
  set_fact:
    my_test: "{{ results.dnac_response | json_query(myquery) }}"
  vars: 
    myquery: "response[*].{ID: id, Attributes: additionalInfo[*].attributes.type}"
```

I managed to obtain this:

```
{
    "my_test": [
        {
            "Attributes": [],
            "ID": "8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": [
                "area"
            ],
            "ID": "1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": [
                "floor"
            ],
            "ID": "33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47"
        }, 
        ...output omitted
```

But I would still to filter that to get "ID" only when attributes is "floor" and create a list that I can use with loop. I now little, so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
    response:
      - additionalInfo: []
        id: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        instanceTenantId: 62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994
        name: Global
        siteHierarchy: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        siteNameHierarchy: Global
      - additionalInfo:
        - attributes: {addressInheritedFrom: 0d5e4dc7, type: area}
          nameSpace: Location
        id: 1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69
        instanceTenantId: 62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994
        name: SOUTH SOUTH
        parentId: 90483b39-e1b3-4135-b1b9-3b7b94d5b2f5
        siteHierarchy: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        siteNameHierarchy: Global/MY NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/SOUTH SOUTH
      - additionalInfo:
        - attributes: {floorIndex: '1', imageURL: '', isCadFile: 'false', rfModel: '103103'}
          nameSpace: mapsSummary
        - attributes: {height: '15.0', length: '100.0', offsetX: '0.0', offsetY: '0.0',
            width: '100.0'}
          nameSpace: mapGeometry
        - attributes: {address: Lisbon, addressInheritedFrom: d518b161, type: floor}
          nameSpace: Location
        id: 33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47
        instanceTenantId: 62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994
        name: FLOOR-1
        parentId: d518b161-85f7-434c-91ae-3eface9cc1d5
        siteHierarchy: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        siteNameHierarchy: Global/MY NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/OEIRAS/ALGES/FLOOR-1
```

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  id_type: "{{ dict(response|
                    json_query('[].[id,
                                    additionalInfo[].attributes.type]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  id_type:
    1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69: [area]
    33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47: [floor]
    8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2: []
```

Select the id

```yaml
  my_test: "{{ id_type|dict2items|
               selectattr('value', 'contains', 'floor')|
               map(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_test:
    - 33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    response:
      - additionalInfo: []
        id: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        instanceTenantId: 62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994
        name: Global
        siteHierarchy: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        siteNameHierarchy: Global
      - additionalInfo:
        - attributes: {addressInheritedFrom: 0d5e4dc7, type: area}
          nameSpace: Location
        id: 1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69
        instanceTenantId: 62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994
        name: SOUTH SOUTH
        parentId: 90483b39-e1b3-4135-b1b9-3b7b94d5b2f5
        siteHierarchy: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        siteNameHierarchy: Global/MY NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/SOUTH SOUTH
      - additionalInfo:
        - attributes: {floorIndex: '1', imageURL: '', isCadFile: 'false', rfModel: '103103'}
          nameSpace: mapsSummary
        - attributes: {height: '15.0', length: '100.0', offsetX: '0.0', offsetY: '0.0',
            width: '100.0'}
          nameSpace: mapGeometry
        - attributes: {address: Lisbon, addressInheritedFrom: d518b161, type: floor}
          nameSpace: Location
        id: 33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47
        instanceTenantId: 62f4c8ab6a041c1c090f7994
        name: FLOOR-1
        parentId: d518b161-85f7-434c-91ae-3eface9cc1d5
        siteHierarchy: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
        siteNameHierarchy: Global/MY NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/OEIRAS/ALGES/FLOOR-1

    id_type: "{{ dict(response|
                      json_query('[].[id,
                                      additionalInfo[].attributes.type]')) }}"
    my_test: "{{ id_type|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value', 'contains', 'floor')|
                 map(attribute='key') }}"
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: id_type|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_test
```

- Optionally, create the list

```yaml
  id_type: "{{ response|
               json_query('[].{id: id,
                               type: additionalInfo[].attributes.type}') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  id_type:
    - id: 8d929134-0c71-48d9-baba-28fb5eab92f2
      type: []
    - id: 1720c283-a903-43f9-996e-a25d63409d69
      type: [area]
    - id: 33e64ab2-641b-4778-adcd-95c832199f47
      type: [floor]
```

Then, the below expression gives the same result

```yaml
  my_test: "{{ id_type|
               selectattr('type',  'contains', 'floor')|
               map(attribute='id') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir, I've seen you always provide good answers in this space. I'll test your suggestion and provide my comments. 

Regards.

Comment: Hi Vladimir I tested your solution by converting to yaml and redirecting content of variable to a yaml file (in my original playbook I'm using a variable, **my_test**, to store the response  as you saw). So, when re-writing that new yaml file to resemble  your playbook above, everything worked.

However, if I try to use define the id_type and the my_test (renamed to my_test2) variable in my original playbook using set_fact, I get the error **'NoneType' object is not iterable. 'NoneType' object is not iterable"}** for id_type. Could you please share any comments on this? Thanks.

Comment: Everything worked for me with the solution provided by Vladimir. Even when testing testing within the same playbook, that part did work by changing value to type and key to id in the **my_test** variable for **selectattr** and **map**. Thanks a lot Vladimir.